# Calculate Angle for Rotation in Pure CSS

Tags: css, math, rotation, css-animations, css-transforms

I would like to use CSS animations to move an SVG along a linear path across a full-window page with aligning the SVG to this path. Referring to the figure below with the path shown as a red line, I want to specify `h` in multiples of vh and `w` in multiples of vw, e.g. `h = 30vh, w = 60vw`, and calculate the angle `α` for rotating the SVG shown as the blue triangle.

Or course, this should be responsive and work with different window sizes. I was hoping to do all this in pure CSS.

[image: Figure showing the linear path with dimensions and angle]

Following `tan(α) = w/h`, I can use the arcus tangens function to calculate the angle `α` from the quotient `w/h`. Since trigonometric function are not available in CSS [yet](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2331#issuecomment-467990627), I could use a series approximation for calculating the angle as demonstrated [here](https://gist.github.com/stereokai/7666bfe93929b14c2dced148c79e0e97). But the actual show-stopper seems to be the calculation of the quotient `w/h` as divisions in CSS require the denominator to be unitless. So, `60vw / 30vh` is not allowed.

Is there a different way to calculate or set the angle in CSS? Or do I have to fall back to a JavaScript solution here?

**Edit:** Here is a minimal reproducible example. In order to set the rotation in the first keyframe, the actual angle `α` would be required. It is currently fixed to `rotate(0deg)` so the triangle always points upwards instead in the direction of the linear path.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  color: black;
  background-color: #8dbdff;
}

svg#example {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: linear-motion 3.0s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes linear-motion {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 30vh) translateX(-100%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(60vw, 0vh) translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<main class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100">
  <svg id="example" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path fill="#008aff" d="M 50,5 95,97.5 5,97.5 z"/>
  </svg>
</main>
```

Comment: Could the requirement be slightly modified to use min? And thanks for your pointer to approximate trig functions, I hadn’t seen that before.

Comment: Do you have some more code of your try?

Comment: I now added a minimal reproducible example which shows the animation without the proper rotation of the SVG. @A Haworth: What exactly do you mean by modify to use min?

Comment: @A Haworth: I think I now understand what you meant. I could use vmin instead of vh and vw. That would allow to pre-calculate the angle as the quotient would stay the same. That is definitely an option, thanks for that idea! The only drawback would be that covering the whole screen would take some extra measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following A Haworth's comment, I finally used `vmin` to create animations with fixed ratios. This ratio can then be used to pre-calculate an angle as shown in the snippet below.

This solution has some limitations but is responsive and works with different window sizes.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  color: black;
  background-color: #8dbdff;
}

svg#example {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: linear-motion 3.0s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes linear-motion {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 40vmin) rotate(66.03deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(90vmin, -100%) rotate(66.03deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<main class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100">
  <svg id="example" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path fill="#008aff" d="M 50,5 95,97.5 5,97.5 z"/>
  </svg>
</main>
```